# Separator for ciphertext and other data

Tags: byte, separator, aes-gcm, initialization-vector

How to store in a file the ciphertext and the IV (of a block cipher mode of operation, e.g. AES-GCM)? If I separate them with a byte corresponding to the ":" character, when reading it I'll have to convert the whole byte array in String and then split the strings into chunks separated by ":" and then again convert the chunks into byte arrays. Is there a simpler way? Maybe a byte that we are sure can't appear as a result of an AES encryption and in a Initialization Vector?

The current code (in Java) is the subsequent, but I'm not sure if it is the best way to perform what I asked and even if it works because I don't know if the byte representing ":" can appear in the IV or the ciphertext.

```
FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream("test");
byte[] byteRead = new byte[keyfis.available()];
keyfis.read(byteRead);
keyfis.close();
String textRead=new String(byteRead); 

String[] parts = textRead.split(":");
byte[] encrAESkey=parts[0].getBytes();
byte[] myIV=parts[1].getBytes();
byte[] myencrtext=parts[2].getBytes();
```

Comment: @SibeeshVenu I'have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally the IV is prepended, as it is required to be exactly one block length (`16 bytes`), and block cipher modes (other than ECB) all require the IV (or nonce + counter). Then your decryption code simply extracts the first `16 bytes` from the cipher text input and uses it as the IV, and performs the decryption operation on the remaining `n - 16 bytes`.

You should use an encoding scheme to protect the cipher text you serialize to the file however, as you will very likely encounter issues if you write/read raw binary bytes. Hexadecimal or Base64 encoding are the standard for this operation.

It also appears from your code that you are storing the AES key alongside the IV and cipher text. While the IV can be stored unprotected alongside the cipher text, **the key cannot** without effectively removing any protection that encryption would provide.

Comment: My code was a first "attempt" to use AES-GCM. In my subsequent codes I stored the IV in a separate column of a table belonging to a DB. Anyway thank you for your answer and yes, I did have some problems in encoding and decoding raw bytes, which I solved using the ISO-8859-1 encoding when I get bytes from a String and when I initialize a String from raw bytes. It's working fine, but I'm interested in knowing if it is a good solution.

Comment: Storing the IV in a separate column really isn't necessary and could lead to fields getting out of sync, which would affect the recoverability of the cipher text. 

Is there a specific reason you are using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8? If so, that's fine, but if you don't have a reason, you probably want to use UTF -- for the plaintext messages. For the cipher text, you'll want to encode that with hex or Base64 before persisting. ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 both use 8 bits per byte (as opposed to ASCII which is 7) but don't guarantee that all possible code points are valid characters. Base64 does.

Comment: Why storing the IV separately could sync out the fields? I'm not using UTF-8 because using it - and I don't know why - made my encryption scheme not working, while - and it's strange of course - it works without any problem with ISO-8859-1. Can you explain why the ciphertext and the plaintext should use different encodings?

Comment: Storing the IV in a different field makes it easier for either the IV or cipher text to be updated as the result of a new encryption operation without modifying the other, and both are tied inextricably to the other. It is not a guarantee that this will happen, but it seems an unnecessary risk.

Comment: Unless you post your whole code, I can't tell you why UTF-8 would cause encryption issues but ISO-8859-1 would not, but UTF is the most common encoding scheme now so I would be surprised if you did not have specific requirements for ISO-8859-1.

Comment: As I mentioned above, both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 use 8 bits to store each byte/character, but they do not guarantee that every possible 8 bit value (0-255) is a valid character in that encoding. Base64 converts a series of 8 bit values into 6 bit values, and because 2^6 = 64, all possible 6 bit values are valid characters in Base64. AES can produce any of the 256 possible combinations of 8 bits (2^8 = 256), so it is important to use an encoding scheme which can handle all possible values.

Comment: Look at [these charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) to see how the encoding from 8 bits to 6 bits occurs.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read more about encoding and then if anything will not be clear yet I'll post a different question. In that case I'd really appreciate an answer from you since your answer and comments had been very helpful.